# Roman Numeral Justification Issue in Memoir TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, page-numbering, roman-numerals

I'm typesetting a book with lengthy frontmatter, but any roman numeral page numbers more than three characters are being pushed into the right margin of the TOC.  How would I fix this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,ebook]{memoir}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Preface}
\setcounter{page}{26}
\chapter{Introduction}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\setcounter{page}{26}
\chapter{Chapter 2}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to adjust `\@pnumwidth` and `\@tocrmarg` to suitable values to accomodate wide page numbers. `memoir`'s way of doing this is

```
\setpnumwidth{3em}  %% default 1.55em
\setrmarg{4em}      %% default 2.55em
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,ebook]{memoir}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
\setpnumwidth{3em}
\setrmarg{4em}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Preface}
\setcounter{page}{26}
\chapter{Introduction}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\setcounter{page}{26}
\chapter{Chapter 2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

FYI, here is a screen shot showing various lengths involved in TOC, LOF etc

[image]